# C implement like cat with robustness and efficiency

Tags: c, cat, unistd.h

I want to learn to implement the function like cat, which just take input from a file and print to stdout.

But I am not sure the line of `write()` is robust in all cases as it may write less than `n`. But I am not able to create a test case to make this case happen. How to make a test case so that it can result in less than n char be written? Also, how to modify the code accordingly to make the program robust (for this case, but also for other cases that I have not described)?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *pathname = argv[1];
    int fd;
    if((fd = open(pathname, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t n;
    while((n = read(fd, &buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
        if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, n) == -1) {
            perror("write");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(n == -1) {
        perror("read");
        return 1;
    }
    if(close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I fixed the `write()` bug in the previous code based on the pipe-blocking test case mentioned by Armali. Can anybody check whether there are any other bugs?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *pathname = argv[1];
    int fd;
    if((fd = open(pathname, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
#define BUF_SIZE 2*65536
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t r_n;
    while((r_n = read(fd, &buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
        ssize_t w_n;
        int i = 0;
        while((w_n = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf+i, r_n)) < r_n) {
            if(w_n == -1) {
                perror("write");
                return 1;
            }
            r_n -= w_n;
            i += w_n;
        }
    }
    if(r_n == -1) {
        perror("read");
        return 1;
    }
    if(close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with your handling of the read or write. (you actually do a very good job validating each step) Why do you want to use syscalls instead of `stdio.h` I/O?

Comment: `write` has  [documented edge cases](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) where less than `n` bytes can be written.  Indeed your code will fail in those cases. The only way I can imagine to test reliably is to mock write (maybe via macro).

Comment: The edge cases you are attempting to emulate will not be common for a simple `cat` program for files less than 2^31 bytes of data. The partial write condition is generally associated with network writes. There you would just loop until `n` bytes had been written keeping track of the number written with each call. The other case is disk-full errors (which won't occur writing to `stdout` unless the entire filesystem if filled by something else (and then it will depend on the implementation) Your use of `read` is already limited to `BUF_SIZE` (`1024` bytes)

Comment: Aside: Drop the `&` in 2 places: `while((n = read(fd, &buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) { if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, n) == -1) {`.  `buf` is sufficient.

Comment: `if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, n) == -1) {` should be `if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, n) != n) {`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make a test case so that it can result in less than n char be written?

Depending on the system, this hasn't to be difficult. `man 2 write` tells:

```
… partial writes can occur for various reasons; for example, because there was
insufficient space on the disk device to write all of the requested bytes, or because
a blocked write() to a socket, pipe, or similar was interrupted by a signal …
```

Let's focus on pipe writes, which block if the pipe buffer is full. This example targets Linux; the numbers may well be different on other systems. `man 7 pipe` tells about the *Pipe capacity*:

```
Since Linux 2.6.11, the pipe capacity is 16 pages (i.e., 65,536 bytes in a system with
a page size of 4096 bytes).
```

To make use of this for the sake of a test case, we have to increase your `BUF_SIZE` to a greater value, say `1024*128`. Then we can conduct the experiment:

```
~$ dd count=256 </dev/zero >zeros
256+0 records in
256+0 records out
131072 bytes (131 kB, 128 KiB) copied, 0.00357324 s, 36.7 MB/s
~$ strace -ewrite ./a.out zeros|(sleep 9; dd)
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 strace -ewrite ./a.out zeros | ( sleep 9; dd )
~$ fg
strace -ewrite ./a.out zeros | ( sleep 9; dd )
) = 65536
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=482, si_uid=2001} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
128+0 records in
128+0 records out
65536 bytes (66 kB, 64 KiB) copied, 0.00546081 s, 12.0 MB/s
```

- First we prepare a file of 128 KiB.
- Then we run the program with `strace -ewrite` to see the write operation; we pipe its output to `(sleep 9; dd)` to delay the reading. During this delay, we raise a STOP signal by pressing Ctrl-Z.
- Finally, we continue the program with `fg`. Now we see that the write operation, which has been called with count `131072`, returns only `65536` bytes written.

> Also, how to modify the code accordingly to make the program robust (for this case, but also for other cases that I have not described)?

For this case and similar cases, you'd do as David C. Rankin wrote:

> There you would just loop until `n` bytes had been written keeping track of the number written with each call.

I can't say how to make a program robust for undescribed cases other than checking the returned values from all called library functions of which you can't be sure that they succeed.

Comment: If `write()` returns 0, can I be sure that `write()` has finished writing all the input instead of a failure?

Comment: No, if _`write(fd, buf, count)` has finished writing all the input_, it returns the passed _count_, hence it could return zero only if you passed a zero _count_, which is not advisable, since the rules for this case are somewhat complicated and partially unspecified.

Comment: So if the count argument of `write()` is none zero, but `write()` returns 0, then I can be sure the write is successfully finished?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _finished_. If 0 is returned, this invocation of `write` is finished without error, but of course the writing of the requested _count_ bytes is not at all finished and has to be retried. Your fixed program does this right.